# Android NFC both ways

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

using ICS 4.0.1 ( will be willing to upgrade to 4.0.3) (will not root and rewrite android OS)

is there anyway to send a NDEF message back to an android phone after receiving an android beam

phone A beams: "hello phone B" 
phone B reply: "hello phone A"

i can get A to beam to B, but how do i get B to beam back to A? (i do not want to move the devices away and touch them again)

Comment: Hi Lawrence L , I am trying to communicate via NFC,I am testing Android Beam example ,I did configured it in my eclipse,how I can send message from my Device A to Device B ? if you can explain some how you did this , very thanks  .

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible. The minute you put the devices together and one device sends the data, the other device will receive it and then lose the touch to beam UI. Currently, using the UI is the only way to beam things over. You can't really do it programmatically. You can beam things simultaneously if both users hit touch to beam at the same time, but the data beamed to one another won't necessarily depend on each other.